# How to Check if Axios Call Fails due to No Internet Connection?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking, server, axios

I'm trying to figure out an accurate way to detect axios call failure due to no internet connection.

Does axios call failure return a specific response object or specific response status code or throw a specific error details for the no internet connection scenario?

Example of what i will use the "**detection of axios failure due to no internet connection**" for

```
try {
    const res = await server.get('/auth/user?', {
            params: {
                refreshToken: refreshToken,            
                userID: userID
            }
        }
    );

    if(res.user.data){
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.user});
    } else {
        if(res.axiosFailsDueToNoInternetConnection){
            alert('no internet connection');
            dispatch({type: RELOAD});
        }
    }

} catch (error) {
    if(error.dueToNoInternetConnection){
        alert('no internet connection');
        dispatch({type: RELOAD});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your catch clause you can check whether the error is caused by network error or not:

```
catch (error) {
    if(error.toJSON().message === 'Network Error'){
        alert('no internet connection');
        dispatch({type: RELOAD});
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could check error.message directly? 

Like: if (error.message === 'Network Error') {....

Comment: This answer is not correct because a "Network error" could also happen in case of a withCredintials pilot request failure

Comment: This will also be the case when the request fails due to CORS error :(

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer is not correct, because a "Network Error" error could also happen in case of a `withCredintials` pilot request failure.

And you must differentiate between a server error and a client-side error by checking whether the `error.response` property object exists or not.

```
catch (error) {
    if(!window.navigator.onLine && !error.response && error.code === "ERR_NETWORK"){
alert('no internet connection');
    }
}
```

I must also mention that the checking for `window.navigator.onLine` **should** be done inside the `try block` before sending and awaiting a request and not in the catch block. However, it must be **almost** correct either ways

Comment: Please note that `error.response` can be `undefined` if the serer just sends a status code without any content.

Answer (score 2):

A better and reliable approach mat be to check the `code` property

```
catch (error) {
    if(error.code === 'ERR_NETWORK'){
        alert('no internet connection');
        dispatch({type: RELOAD});
    }
}
```